# Why doesn't this compile

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-errors, poco-libraries

```
#include "base.h"
#include <Poco/SharedPtr.h>
#include <Poco/AutoPtr.h>
#include <vector>

using Poco::SharedPtr;
using Poco::AutoPtr;


namespace kroll
{
    class Value;
    class KObject;
    class KMethod;
    class KList;

    class StaticBoundObject;
    class StaticBoundMethod;
    class StaticBoundList;

    class GlobalObject;
    class ScopeMethodDelegate;
    class Bytes;
    class VoidPtr;
    class ValueReleasePolicy;
    class Logger;
    class ArgList;

    template <class C>
    class KAutoPtr : public AutoPtr<C>
    {
    public:
        KAutoPtr() : AutoPtr()
        {}

        KAutoPtr(C* ptr) : AutoPtr(ptr)
        {}

        KAutoPtr(C* ptr, bool shared) : AutoPtr(ptr, shared)
        {}

        KAutoPtr(const AutoPtr& ptr) : AutoPtr(ptr)
        {}

        /*KAutoPtr& operator = (const AutoPtr& ptr)
        {
            return assign(ptr);
        }*/

#ifdef DEBUG
        //This is used in debug builds as a workaround to release all memory
        //before VS debugger incorrectly dumps it as memory leak.
        KObject* release()
        {
            KObject* t = _ptr;
            _ptr = 0;
            return t;
        }
#endif
    };
```

I get the following errors:

```
kroll/libkroll/kroll.h:66: error: expected ',' or '...' before '&' token
kroll/libkroll/kroll.h:66: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'AutoPtr' with no type
kroll/libkroll/kroll.h: In constructor 'kroll::KAutoPtr<C>::KAutoPtr()':
kroll/libkroll/kroll.h:57: error: class 'kroll::KAutoPtr<C>' does not have any field named 'AutoPtr'
kroll/libkroll/kroll.h: In constructor 'kroll::KAutoPtr<C>::KAutoPtr(C*)':
kroll/libkroll/kroll.h:60: error: class 'kroll::KAutoPtr<C>' does not have any field named 'AutoPtr'
kroll/libkroll/kroll.h: In constructor 'kroll::KAutoPtr<C>::KAutoPtr(C*, bool)':
kroll/libkroll/kroll.h:63: error: class 'kroll::KAutoPtr<C>' does not have any field named 'AutoPtr'
kroll/libkroll/kroll.h: In constructor 'kroll::KAutoPtr<C>::KAutoPtr(int)':
kroll/libkroll/kroll.h:66: error: class 'kroll::KAutoPtr<C>' does not have any field named 'AutoPtr'
kroll/libkroll/kroll.h:66: error: 'ptr' was not declared in this scope
kroll/libkroll/kroll.h: In member function 'kroll::KObject* kroll::KAutoPtr<C>::release()':
kroll/libkroll/kroll.h:79: error: '_ptr' was not declared in this scope
```

line 66 is KAutoPtr(const AutoPtr& ptr) : AutoPtr(ptr)

I am using the command line i686-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.2.1 to compile the code on MAC OS X 10.6.7 machine.

Comment: Maybe it's not syntactically correct?

Comment: *Sigh.* Start small, build up, test at every step. Never add to code that doesn't work.

Comment: @Beta: To be fair, there's hardly any code there at all.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth There's 14 classes in total, that is 14 header and cpp files that need to be linked, thats a lot of code for me, about 29 files at least........

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Line 66 should be this:

```
KAutoPtr() : AutoPtr<C>()
```

And similarly for the other constructor calls.

Comment: Thanks!  This code was checked in and worked for someone on my team working with Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 but broke my compile over on the MAC side.

Answer (score 0):

You have written the body of the `KAutoPtr` template as if `KAutoPtr<C>` derived from `AutoPtr`. But it does not; there is no type `AutoPtr`; `AutoPtr` is a template, and `KAutoPtr<C>` derives from `AutoPtr<C>`.